# Macro Syntax Confusion

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have gone through the concepts of macros but never encountered

```
#define reg_add_cfghwmod_beacon_led_control(a,b) \
_reg_add_cfghwmod_beacon_led_control(a)
```

This kind of syntax can any one explain me what the above macro means.

Comment: Which part don't you understand? The \ at the end of first line, or why is the argument `b` missing, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a multi-line MACRO.

- Regarding the trailing `\`, if you see the syntax of a `#define` directive, `C11` standard, chapter §6.10,  it says,

  ```
  # define identifier replacement-list new-line
  ```

so, a *newline* ends the *replacement-list* and effectively, the directive. So, to have multi-lined definition of `#define` directive, the `\` is used to escape the newline and to make the statements of the follwing line as a part of the replacement list of the same MACRO.

- Regarding the loss of `b` in the MACRO definition,

Depends on coding logic. Maybe an attempt to *fallback* to some earlier version of API having only one argument. Pure guesswork

**TL;DR;** All it does is to replace the text <sup>(Possibly a function call)</sup>

```
reg_add_cfghwmod_beacon_led_control(a,b)
```

with

```
_reg_add_cfghwmod_beacon_led_control(a)
```

Comment: I also thought so but then. I was wondering why the hell some one will first use two arguments in a macro and then use the similar name with just one argument.

Comment: @RohitSaluja You never know, maybe the `(a,b)` part was implemented as a wrapper for some newer version, but they wanted to fall back to the earlier version with 1 argument. Just maybe

Comment: This can be used to evolve APIs where, in a different version, the second argument is not used, or to configure some piece of code in an environment where a second argument is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

As Sourav Ghosh says above, it is a multiline macro (the `\` at the end). Also, it is a little bit unnatural, because what it does is ignoring the second argument. The substitution does not consider the `b` argument. Otherwise, it is as any other macro.